# Get the Youtube Video Format

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have a Youtube URL (ID) and I need to adjust some script depending of the video format of that video.

How do we find out the format (16:9 or another) and resolution of a video on Youtube, having it's ID?

Comment: What format? There can be many different formats available for a single video.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need the **aspect ratio** of a video, you can use something like https://noembed.com/ (or you can use YouTube's oEmbed API directly; see https://oembed.com/).

Example:

`GET http://noembed.com/embed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysk2OzngYIg`

```
{  
  "height":270,
  "thumbnail_url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ysk2OzngYIg/hqdefault.jpg",
  "thumbnail_width":480,
  "author_name":"Jamie Syme",
  "url":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysk2OzngYIg",
  "title":"test: sample coast",
  "width":480,
  "provider_name":"YouTube",
  "thumbnail_height":360,
  "provider_url":"https://www.youtube.com/",
  "type":"video",
  "author_url":"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7x7nMO0Y9Fq0g7q5zyDC2Q",
  "html":"\n<iframe width=\" 480\" height=\"270\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/ysk2OzngYIg?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\"></iframe>\n",
  "version":"1.0"
}
```

Diving the `width` by the `height` will give you the aspect ratio.

If, however, you need the **actual resolution** of the uploaded video, you'll need to go through [YouTube's Video List API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list), and you'll need to be the owner of the video.

Example:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=ysk2OzngYIg&part=fileDetails`

```
/**
 * API response
 */
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/nkmtubhIzKeVfaCtEq3-HIJf0mw\"",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/er5srVttLDLwfS6A6I4VKsvOmH4\"",
      "id": "ysk2OzngYIg",
      "fileDetails": {
        "fileName": "sample-coast.mp4",
        "fileSize": "13586259",
        "fileType": "video",
        "container": "mov",
        "videoStreams": [
          {
            "widthPixels": 1920,
            "heightPixels": 1080,
            "frameRateFps": 29.97002997002997,
            "aspectRatio": 1.7777777777777777,
            "codec": "h264",
            "bitrateBps": "4238925"
          }
        ],
        "durationMs": "24290",
        "bitrateBps": "4238925"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*Note that the response above was received through the embedded API tester in their docs.*

Comment: suppose I use this link `https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4LoM208_Ow`: https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4LoM208_Ow ... where is the supposed 800x600?

Comment: the same question for the https://noembed.com/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DR4LoM208_Ow

Comment: The `width` and `height` fields from either of those responses can be used to determine the aspect ratio (`459 / 344 = 1.33 -> 4:3`). As for the actual resolutions that YouTube has for a particular video, you'll probably have to look into the API here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list . I haven't used the API before, so I'm unsure on the specifics.

Comment: on the latest link you gave, I tried my `R4LoM208_Ow` test, but didn't obtain anyway any 800 nor 600 in their response

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example response that I received for a video that I just uploaded; it contains the width and height of the original.

Comment: I tried to obtain "fileDetails", and got: "Note that the fileDetails, processingDetails, and suggestions parts are only available to that videos owner."

Comment: once again, I just tried to obtain data from the example above R4LoM208_Ow

Comment: Ahh. In that case, it looks like the closest you can get from their API is to swap "fileDetails" for "contentDetails" and check if the `definition` field is set to "sd" (standard definition) or "hd" (high definition).